# CSS flex is shrinking the wrong item

Tags: css, flexbox

My expected outcome here is the yellow box will remain static in width, the red box will remain static in width, the white box with a red outline will shrink and grow to fill the space with the page resizing

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.main {
  display:flex-box;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100vw - 822px);
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  min-width: calc(100vw - 822px);
}

.right {
  display:flex-box;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  flex: 1;
}

.right-content {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is not what is happening at all, the yellow box is completely flexible while the white box with a red outline remains static until the yellow box has disappeared

Comment: you are defining the width of yellow using vw so how do you expect it to remain static?

Comment: very well spotted, that calculation determines the  initial width that it needs to be, I didn't consider that it would recalculate on screen resize. if I set a hardcoded pixel width would this work as I expect?

I wonder if there is a better way for me to calculate that initial width. I guess I could use javascript, not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `display: flex-box` is wrong. There is no such property. If you'd like the yellow box to be static, you need to give it a static width, no `calc`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.main {
  background-color: #ff0;
    width: 300px
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  flex: 1;
}

.right-content {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```